# Gitea webhook context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: webhooks, drone.io, gitea, github-webhook

We installed Gitea and DroneCI in an EKS cluster using helm. We are using AWS NLB IPs to establish communication between them. DroneCI was able to authorize and activate the repo inside Gitea. But when we update any files inside Gitea it fails to send the webhook to the DroneCI server with the below error.

```
Delivery: Post "http://10.22x.xx.xx/hook?secret=qIGg8hkgiBo8nEiiwirhTxwlNWvGEv0": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

We even have a proper `.drone.yml` file in the repo as per the suggestion from this [link](https://discourse.gitea.io/t/client-timeout-exceeded-while-awaiting-headers/4148).
Please help how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
[webhook]
ALLOWED_HOST_LIST=*
```

Try to add the above entry in the Gitea config file (`app.ini`).
If this works, please add the proper endpoint instead of `*`